# Python: pdf2image doesn't write .jpg - no error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf2image

I'm working on a python script that checks the .pdf files in a directory, creates a new directory for each file, converts the .pdf into images, and writes the images as jpg into the new directory. I'm using pdf2image and have the following code:

```py
import os
#import main
import glob
#import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image

path = "C:/Users/d/Desktop/Reis/"

for file in glob.iglob(path + "*.pdf"):
    print(file)
    name = os.path.basename(file)
    filename = name.split(".")[0]
    print(filename)
    images = os.mkdir(path + filename)
    pages = convert_from_path("C:/Users/d/Desktop/Reis/Reis_Wasser_Verhaeltnis.pdf",
                              350,
                              poppler_path=r'C:/Program Files/poppler-22.04.0/Library/bin',
                              output_folder=images)

    for i in range(len(pages)):
        pages[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

When I run my code I don't get an error message but no images either. Does anyone have an idea what I'm overseeing?

Comment: Do you get any output from any of your `print(file)` and print(filename)` statements?

Comment: yes, the print outputs work as expected. Furthermore, "os.mkdir" creates the folder as expected.

Comment: after adding a "print(pages[i])" under the save() statement (still inside the for loop) I get the following output: 
"<PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2894x4093 at 0x2C3DE4F8D50>

<PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2894x4093 at 0x2C3DE014510>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.mkdir` creates the Folder but it is of type boolean. Thus:

```
images = os.mkdir(path + filename)
```

returns only `True` and cannot be used as the output folder. My script writes the images into the default project directory.